# Request to Host DirectAdmin or Cpanel with python or ...?

Tags: python, request, cpanel, web-hosting, directadmin

I have a website on internet www.exampl.com  and that set in DirectAdmin (or can set on Cpanel). How can I request to my table database?

In SQL with Python:

```
import pyodbc
db = pyodbc.connect ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.;Database=DatabaseName Trusted_Connection=yes;")    
CUR = db.cursor() 
sql="SELECT Col1, Col2,Col3 from TableName"
CUR .execute(sql)
response=CUR.fetchone()
```

And done.

Is there a way?

In local database like SQL Server I send request to MySql database on my Host in internet and I receive my response.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find my Answer on this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VL1oslamzE0) is video tutorial. Just set my IP dedicate or  range Ip my ISP.